# CalculateCircleArea Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```js
function calculateCircleArea(r) {
  // return the area of a circle with radius r
  // round result to 3 decimal numbers
  let area = (r * r * Math.PI);
  return area.toFixed(Number(3));
}
console.log(calculateCircleArea(1));
```

It is returning the error: 
AssertionError: expected '3.142' to equal 3.142

Can anyone help?

Comment: It is not outputting any error , if you run here also.

Comment: Note `'3.142'` isn't equal (`===`) to 3.142 one is a string the other is a number. `toFixed()` returns a string. So your assert test is correct

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`parseFloat`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp)** convert string to decimal number

> `toFixed()` return as string.So you need to convert to number

```js
function calculateCircleArea(r) {
  let area = (r * r * Math.PI);
  return parseFloat(area.toFixed(3));
}
console.log(calculateCircleArea(1));
console.log(typeof(calculateCircleArea(1)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however I am still getting the same issue?

Comment: can you describe your issue?

Comment: AssertionError: expected '3.142' to equal 3.142

Comment: use `==` instead `===` . Because `string === number` always false